# Adding Redux Provider store to the main index file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I was thinking about passing my `<Provider store={Store}>` directly to my main `index.js` file:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

I mean, I know we can always do something like this in our `App.js` :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from "./src/store.js"  
import Something from './src/container/Something.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <Something />     
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I was wondering if we can do it in `Index.js`, and if so then how?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On `index.js` you could create another component wrapping `App`:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Store from "./src/store.js"  
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

const Root = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Root);
```